# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

Do you know `repl.it`?

I am coding python on this site.
And my goal is creating `Web Scraper`.
I think this code is clean.
But I'm getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'text'
```

---

My code:

```
import requests

indeed_result = requests.get
("https://kr.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=%EC%9D%B8%EC%B2%9C")

print(indeed_result.text)
```

---

Surely, I have requests package installed.
Please give me some advice

Comment: for me, the code is not giving any error. You can try as mentioned by @Walid's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the back to new line after get like this:

```
import requests

indeed_result = requests.get("https://kr.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=%EC%9D%B8%EC%B2%9C")

print(indeed_result.text)
```

if you want to continue typping in the next line just add a backslash `\` as follows:

```
indeed_result = requests.get\
("https://kr.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=%EC%9D%B8%EC%B2%9C")
```

Comment: The editor should show that mistake while writing the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Removing back to new line after get

try this

```
import requests

res = requests.get("https://kr.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=%EC%9D%B8%EC%B2%9C")
print(res.text)

# result if success 200
```